# How to change fragment with the Bottom Navigation Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I created a new project with the "Bottom Navigation Activity":

[image]

This is the generated code:

```
package com.aaron.waller.mrpolitik;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView mTextMessage;

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
            }
            return true;
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTextMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    }

}
```

How can I change to new Fragments with the Bottom Bar?
For example I have 3 Fragments:
Fragment1
Fragment2 and
Fragment3
And I want to change to them with the 3 buttons from the Bottom Bar.
Also I want that I can switch the Fragments by swiping my finger left and right how can I do that?

Comment: Regarding the swipe action: Using swipe gestures on the content area does not navigate between views, check the design guidelines of the Bottom Navigation at https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-behavior

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The way I would do it is, I would first add three methods similar to this one (each for a single fragment. Replace the layout name and the fragment object to the appropriate fragment that is being switched to):

```
public void switchToFragment1() {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.your_fragment_layout_name, new Fragment1()).commit();
}
```

So your switch statement would end up looking like this:

```
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_home);
                switchToFragment1();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_dashboard);                    
                switchToFragment2();
                break;

            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);                     
                switchToFragment3();
                break;
        }
```

As for switching the fragments by swiping to the sides, I believe you would need a [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html).

Comment: As per Google Material docs, swiping shouldn't used (Avoid using lateral motion to transition between views) when Bottom Navigation is used.
https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-behavior

Comment: @bitvale https://medium.com/@oluwabukunmi.aluko/bottom-navigation-view-with-fragments-a074bfd08711

Comment: For newer implementations, instead of using  fragment transactions, use :     navController.navigate(R.id.thirdFragment)

Answer (score 11):

It's pretty "simple".

1. Create your Fragments. Let's say we want 3 fragments; `FragmentA`, `FragmentB` and `FragmentC` with `FragmentA` being the first Fragment we want on the BottomNavigationView.
2. In your Activity, go to the `onNavigationItemSelected` method and change the content to this:

   ```
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  
      mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
          = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){

      @Override
      public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

       switch (item.getItemId()) {
           case R.id.frag_a:
               currentFragment = new FragmentA();
               ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
               ft.replace(R.id.content, currentFragment);
               ft.commit();
               return true;
           case R.id.frag_b:
               currentFragment = new FragmentB();
               ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
               ft.replace(R.id.content, currentFragment);
               ft.commit();
               return true;
           case R.id.frag_c:
               currentFragment = new FragmentC();
               ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
               ft.replace(R.id.content, currentFragment);
               ft.commit();
               return true;
       }

       return false;
    }

   };
   ```
3. In your `onCreate()`method, do this:

   ```
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_profile);
       ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
       currentFragment = new FragmentA();
       ft.replace(R.id.content, currentFragment);
       ft.commit();

       BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView)  
       findViewById(R.id.navigation); navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
     }
   ```

If you do not add `FragmentA` in the `onCreate()`, the activity is blank when you first launch it.

If you are wondering what `R.id.content` refers to, it is the Id of the Framelayout in your activity's layout. It initially contains a `TextView`, delete the TextView so it looks like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Finally, `ft` and `currentFragment` are defined like this:

```
Fragment currentFragment = null;
FragmentTransaction ft;
```

Not sure about elegance, but this works.

Answer (score 9):

The best way is to use a `ViewPager` with a `FragmentPagerAdapter`. Since it cashes the fragments inside it. Use `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener` with the `BottomNavigationView` to listen for the user's clicks. And use `viewPager.setCurrentItem(..)` to move between pages.

Creating a new fragment everytime the user clicks on an item in the bottom navigation view isn't a good solution (especially when the user clicks on the item of the screen that he is currently at, the solution above will create a new fragment even for this case)

Comment: Your solution seems interesting, however can you provide a sample code?

Comment: not a good solutions, it is not possible to disable swipe on viewpager easily

Answer (score 7):

You can switch fragments through below code if you are using Jetpack Navigation.

```
val navController = findNavController(R.id.your_nav_host_fragment)
navController.navigate(R.id.your_fragment_id_in_menu)
```

For more information go through this doc : https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/#0

Answer (score 2):

```
//fully tested  
  public class DashBoardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

        private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
                = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_home:
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                        fragment = new FragmentDashBoard();
                        switchFragment(fragment);
                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                        fragment = new FragmentNotification();
                        switchFragment(fragment);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };


        private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
            fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

            BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
            navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
            navigation.setSelectedItemId(R.id.navigation_dashboard);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is with the Navigation Component:

```
 bottom_navigation_view?.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Comment: yes! this works perfectly! But can you also change/switch fragments programmatically with this? Any documentation on that?

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to avoid recreating fragment -- `fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(aimFragment)`

My example is follow(just copy from my project recent):

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @BindView(R.id.main_bottom_navigation) BottomNavigationView mBottomNavigationView;
    final Fragment mTaskListFragment = new TaskListFragment();
    final Fragment mUserGroupFragment = new UserGroupFragment();
    final Fragment mUserMeFragment = new UserMeFragment();
    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment active = mTaskListFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        mBottomNavigationView
                .setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_fragment_container, mUserMeFragment, "3")
                .hide(mUserMeFragment).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_fragment_container, mUserGroupFragment, "2")
                .hide(mUserGroupFragment).commit();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_fragment_container, mTaskListFragment, "1").commit();

    }


    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = item -> {
//        TODO： 这种切换方式比较快，但横竖屏切换会出问题，已经
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_list:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(mTaskListFragment).commit();
                    active = mTaskListFragment;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_group:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(mUserGroupFragment).commit();
                    active = mUserGroupFragment;
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_me:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(mUserMeFragment).commit();
                    active = mUserMeFragment;
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        };
}
```

It seems efficient and will work well until you rotate your phone. And I fixed it by adding the code following in the manifest file to the activity to retain the fragment state. (e.g. at `AndroidManifest.xml`):

```
android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|screenLayout"
```

Answer (score 1):

Its my suggest way and it has an ideal performance
I did it with using `naveController` and `androidx.navigation:navigation`

Step 1: Add the navigation dependency to your app-level `build.gradle` file. This will allow you to use the Navigation component in your app.

```
dependencies {
def nav_version = "2.3.5"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
}
```

Step 2: Create a new menu resource file for the bottom navigation bar. This file will contain the menu items that will be displayed in the bar. To create a new menu resource file, right-click on the res folder in the Project panel, select `New > Android resource file`, and set the Resource type to Menu.

Step 3: In the menu resource file, add the menu items that will be displayed in the bottom navigation bar. Each menu item should have a unique ID and a title. For example:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:title="Home" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
    android:title="Dashboard" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
    android:title="Notifications" />
```

Step 4: In the layout file where you want to display the bottom navigation bar, add a BottomNavigationView element. For example:

```
   <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu"
/>
```

Note that the app:menu attribute is set to the name of the menu resource file created in step 2.

Step 5: In your activity or fragment that will host the bottom navigation bar, create an instance of NavController using the findNavController() method and pass in the BottomNavigationView as the argument. For example:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
app:startDestination="@id/navigation_home">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_home"
    android:name="com.example.myapp.HomeFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_home" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_dashboard"
    android:name="com.example.myapp.DashboardFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_dashboard" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_notifications"
    android:name="com.example.myapp.NotificationsFragment"
    android:label="@string/title_notifications" />
```

Note that each fragment is identified by a unique ID, which corresponds to the ID of the menu item in the bottom navigation bar.

That's it! With these steps, you should now have a basic bottom navigation bar that can be used to replace different fragments in your app.

Answer (score -2):

you can use this one

```
                    fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                    transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

                    FragmentA a = new FragmentA();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame, a);
                    transaction.commit();
```