# Activity re-created on bottom navigation view

Tags: android, android-activity, bottomnavigationview

Following is my code for bottom navigation view item selected

```
public static void  setupBottomNavigationView(BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationViewEx){
        Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomNavigationView: Setting up NavigationView1");
        bottomNavigationViewEx.enableAnimation(false);
        bottomNavigationViewEx.enableItemShiftingMode(false);
        bottomNavigationViewEx.enableShiftingMode(false);
        bottomNavigationViewEx.setTextVisibility(false);
    }

      public static void enableNavigation(final Context context, BottomNavigationViewEx view){
    view.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment fragment;
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    fragment = new FragmentMarker();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_bookmark:
                    fragment = new FragmentBookmark();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_blog:
                    fragment = new FragmentBlog();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_notification:
                    fragment = new FragmentNotification();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_account:
                    fragment = new FragmentAccount();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;

            }
           return false;
        }
    });
 }
```

Is there any way to display fragments on bottom navigation bar selected without re-creating activity?

Comment: why are you creating an activity for every action? create a frame inside main activity and bind all fragment to that frame

Comment: Yes, useing fragments

Comment: but you are starting the new activity

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46600951/6891563

Answer (score 1):

```
       @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            Fragment fragment;
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    fragment = new HomeFragment();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_bookmark:
                    fragment = new BookmarkFragment();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_blog:
                    fragment = new BlogFragment();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;

            }

            return false;
        }
    };

    private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        // load fragment
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Comment: cannot resolve getSupportFragmentManager()
and what is in frame_container?

Comment: About getSupportFragmentManager(), does your activity extends AppCompatActivity?

Also, frame_container is a Frame inside your Activity. You can bind all your fragments to this frame_container.

Comment: You can have a detailed look into bottom navigation view at: https://www.androidhive.info/2017/12/android-working-with-bottom-navigation/

Comment: I have a method `enableNavigation` and it should be static. But `getSupportFragmentManager()` cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: did you try passing getSupportFragmentManager() as a parameter to your function enableNavigation()? Please edit your question and add more necessary codes

Comment: I edited my question. I am using this library https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx because i need to block animation in bottom navigation view

Comment: Change function `enableNavigation()` to `enableNavigation(final Context context, final BottomNavigationViewEx view, final FragmentManager supportFragmentManager)` and pass `getSupportFragmentManager()` as a parameter to `enableNavigation()`

Comment: it did not help