# BottomNavigationView switching tabs displays old fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I have scrounged stack overflow for this answer for hours now and still can't find the answer.

Basically what I'm trying to do is display a login screen on two of the bottom tabs if a user is not logged in and display the actual tab information if the user is logged in. Here is what I have so far.

MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

      AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_tour_market,
                R.id.navigation_tours,
                R.id.navigation_profile)
                .build();

      NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);

      NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);

      NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);

      bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

                    // This means there is no user logged in
                    if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {

                        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.navigation_tour_market:
                                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new TourMarketFragment()).commit();
                                return true;
                            case R.id.navigation_tours:
                            case R.id.navigation_profile:
                                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new LoginFragment()).commit();
                                return true;
                        }
                    }
                    else {

                        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.navigation_tour_market:
                                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new TourMarketFragment()).commit();
                                return true;
                            case R.id.navigation_tours:
                                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new ToursFragment()).commit();
                                return true;
                            case R.id.navigation_profile:
                                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, new ProfileFragment()).commit();
                                return true;
                        }

                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

So the issue that I am having here is when I first boot up the app, it is not displaying the login fragment, but instead showing the initial fragment its supposed to show. When I click on one of the two tabs that I want to show the login screen, it correctly shows the login screen, but its also displaying the original fragment in the background. Its seems as though the fragment is not being replaced or something along those lines.

I've also tried clearing the backstack by calling this before going into any switch statement:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() ; i++) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```

[image]

Comment: You cannot and should not ever be doing any `FragmentTransaction` when you are using the Navigation Component.

Comment: I followed the top answers listed here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43104485/how-to-change-fragment-with-the-bottom-navigation-activity 

Could you please tell me the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Navigation [already does that for you](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#bottom_navigation) - that's what the `NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);` is doing.

Comment: There's also a [whole documentation page on doing login](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional#login).