# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added when I have a BottomNavigationBar - maybe multiple instances of fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

This is complicated but, I have a section in my app (the "run" section) which has a bottom navigation bar with 4 icons/fragments. When I "run" the first time it all works well. When I "run" the second time the app crashes as soon as I click on one of the items in a recyclerview listed in the main/default (or first) fragment of the navigation bar. The error I receive is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added
```

I think one of the complexities is that the "run" section of the app is a Fragment which has the BottomNavigationView in it. All examples seem to have this in the activity.

I have read that can be a general error, but I did notice that a log message which occurs when a recyclerview item is clicked in main/default fragment seems to go from be duplicated as if there are multiple instances:

First Run:

```
2021-07-29 07:51:37.996  D/RunScenarioFragment: showDialog: dialog is null
2021-07-29 07:51:37.996  D/RunScenarioFragment: showDialog: creating new dialog
```

Second Run:

```
2021-07-29 07:53:04.565  D/RunScenarioFragment: showDialog: dialog is null
2021-07-29 07:53:04.565  D/RunScenarioFragment: showDialog: creating new dialog
2021-07-29 07:53:04.575  D/RunScenarioFragment: showDialog: dialog is NOT null
2021-07-29 07:53:04.575  D/RunScenarioFragment: showDialog: no need to create new dialog.
2021-07-29 07:53:04.580  D/RunScenarioFragment: showDialog: dialog is NOT null
2021-07-29 07:53:04.580  D/RunScenarioFragment: showDialog: no need to create new dialog.
```

The code in the bottomnavigationbar is as follows, which seems to be reasonable based on [other examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43104485/how-to-change-fragment-with-the-bottom-navigation-activity) in so:

```
private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout_run_scenario, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

Are multiple instances of the same fragment being created? I don't know how that could happen. I guess it must be when I create the fragment w/the BottomNavigationBar but that is really just a Navigation call. Maybe when I exit but again I simply navigate away:

```
navController.navigate(R.id.action_global_scenarioListFragment2);
```

Here is my listener:

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

            Fragment selectedFragment;

            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.runScenarioDashboardFragment:   //nav_scenario_run_home
                    selectedFragment = new RunScenarioDashboardFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.runScenarioLogFragment:       //nav_scenario_run_log
                    selectedFragment = new RunScenarioLogFragment();
                    break;
                case R.id.runScenarioCommunicationFragment:     //communication fragment

                    selectedFragment = new RunScenarioCommunicationFragment();
                    break;
                default:
                    selectedFragment = new RunScenarioTokenFragment();
                    break;
            }

            switchFragment(selectedFragment);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

**UPDATE**
It seems to be related to an custom AppCompatDialogFragment I am calling.

The code I have for the bottom navigation is working fine. It was not this part of the code causing a problem. It was the AppCompatDialogFragment getting called multiple times.

My fault. Thank you for the help.

Comment: When you call switchFragment(Fragment fragment), are you passing new fragment instance or the already defined fragment object? If you are creating new Fragment everytime when calling switchFragment(Fragment fragment), try to pass already created instance of Fragment in switchFragment(Fragment fragment)

Comment: Interesting. Let me look at that. It is a new fragment. I will add that code to show. It seems like the example I reference is doing it wrong as well, correct? These fragments seem to persist if that’s the problem. I’ve never seen any code to unload them.

Comment: Just try like this Fragment mFragment = new YOURFRAGMENT() and then call switchFragment(mFragment)

Comment: I added the code to the thread showing how I call it. I do use what you are saying but it is not a "m" or module level variable. However it does reflect how others seem to be doing it. I followed a CodingInFlow example on YouTube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not the above code. That is working as intended. It was multiple calls to a AppCompatDialogFragment which was causing the issue. The above code worked fine for the BottomNavigationView.

Thank you everybody for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment class declare Fragments as follows

```
RunScenarioDashboardFragment runScenarioDashboardFragment;
RunScenarioLogFragment runScenarioLogFragment;
RunScenarioCommunicationFragment runScenarioCommunicationFragment;
RunScenarioTokenFragment runScenarioTokenFragment

@Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        runScenarioDashboardFragment = new RunScenarioDashboardFragment();
        runScenarioLogFragment = new RunScenarioLogFragment();
        runScenarioCommunicationFragment = new RunScenarioCommunicationFragment();
        runScenarioTokenFragment = new RunScenarioTokenFragment();

    }

@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // your onCreateView implementation
    }
```

update your navigation listener as

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
        Fragment selectedFragment=null;

        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.runScenarioDashboardFragment:   //nav_scenario_run_home
                selectedFragment = runScenarioDashboardFragment;
                break;
            case R.id.runScenarioLogFragment:       //nav_scenario_run_log
                selectedFragment = runScenarioLogFragment;
                break;
            case R.id.runScenarioCommunicationFragment:     //communication fragment

                selectedFragment = runScenarioCommunicationFragment;
                break;
            default:
                selectedFragment = runScenarioTokenFragment;
                break;
        }

        switchFragment(selectedFragment);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Also update your switchFragment()

```
private void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    
    // this will popout the fragment in back stack if it was there and then 
    // begin the new transaction, add following code only if you add fragment to back stack
    if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount()>0)
        getSupportFragmentManager()..popBackStack();

    fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout_run_scenario, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

or just simply do not add in the back stack

```
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout_run_scenario,    fragment).commit();
```

Comment: i think the only trick here is not to add in the back stack OR if added in backstack then popping out from back stack before replacing new fragment